# Load dependent DLL’s from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, automation, excel-addins, xll

We have a library (XLL file) which we load from network drive to Excel via RegisterXLL method through Excel automation from C# code. Recently we switched to VS2010, and now instead of having single xll for our library it requires msvcp100.dll and msvcr100.dll to be loaded as well (we see it in dependency walker).

It is OK if PC has VS2010 installed, then these files are in C:\WINDOWS\system32\ folder, but for regular users this is not the case. And we can’t distribute these two files among them.
If we put these files into the same network folder, they will not be loaded from there.
Is there any way to force Excel to load these files at the same time when we load our library?

Answer (score 1):

These files are the MS C runtime.

If you don't want to redistribute them then you should just use static linking.  You get static linking with the /MT linker option.

On the other hand, its no real trouble to install the runtime re-distributable. In fact you should have been doing so before with your older version of Visual Studio, but you were getting away with it because some other programs would have installed it before.